# busqueda controller spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Intento pasar 2 parametros desde mi controller de angular, es un formulario de busqueda con 2 parametros, estoy utilizando `jdbcTemplate`, pero mi problema es que no sé donde se ponen los parametros o de que manera.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/empleado/buscarEmpleado", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<Void> buscarEmpleado(@RequestBody String ap_pat,String ap_mat, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
            //System.out.println("Creando Usuario " + emp.getcUsuario());
     
//          if (tabEmpleadoRepository.isEmpleadoExiste(emp)) {
//              System.out.println("A User with name " + emp.getCUsuario()+ " already exist");
//              return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
//          }
                

     
            tabEmpleadoRepository.BuscarFamiliar(ap_pat,ap_mat);
                //int cod=ap_.getnCodEmpleadoPk();
                
                //tabFamiliarRepository.nuevoFamiliar(fam,cod);
     
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
           // headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/empleado/{nCodEmpleadoPk}").buildAndExpand(emp.getNCodEmpleadoPk()).toUri());
               //  headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/empleado/buscarEmpleado").buildAndExpand(emp.getnCodEmpleadoPk()).toUri());
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Dónde quieres pasar los parámetro en el body o en la request? Quizás deberías editar tu pregunta añadiendo más información.

Comment: Esa es mi duda donde se ponen los parametros

Answer (score 0):

Viendo la pregunta parece que quieres hacer un POST y enviar los parámetro en el body. Para ello puedes crear una clase que contenga los parámetros:

```
public class ParametrosBusqueda{
    String ap_pat;
    String ap_mat:
    //getters y setters
}
```

y la función del controlador quedaría de esta forma:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/empleado/buscarEmpleado", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> buscarEmpleado(@RequestBody ParametrosBusqueda parametrosBusqueda, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
    //procesar los valores que están en el objeto parametrosBusqueda
}
```